# How to convert Hex string to IEEE754 Float number with Raku?

Tags: raku, pack, unpack

In Python, `unpack` can convert Hex string to IEEE754 Float number:

```py
import struct

print(struct.unpack('<f', bytes.fromhex("00000042"))[0]) # 32.0
```

`<` represents LITTLE ENDIAN byte order, and `f` represents Float format.

How to convert Hex string to IEEE754 Float number with Raku?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the conversion is supposed to do, what does the string "00000042" represent? A hexadecimal number as a string? Or a list of bytes `00 00 00 42`? And what is the number 32.0? If you enter "00000052" in your Python code above you get `137438953472.0`, is that intended?

Comment: Anyway, in Raku you might be after something like `say "00000042".encode>>.base(16)[*-1].Rat.raku`.

Comment: @Marijn `00000042` is a list of bytes: `00 00 00 42`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible approach is:

1. Parse it into an integer
2. Write the integer into a `Buf`
3. Read a floating point number from that `Buf`

For example:

```
say do given Buf.new {
    .write-int32(0, :16("00000042"), BigEndian);
    .read-num32(0)
}
```

Which gives the same output (32) as the Python example.